# Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have develop a small asp.net MVC3 application in that i have upload a video files into Application server path.When i upload 2MB video file it is uploded .But when itry to upload 50mb file it is showing error like .

```
        This webpage is not available
 The webpage at http://localhost:1318/Campaign/Advertises might be temporarily down or it                
 may have moved permanently to a new web address.
 Here are some suggestions:
 Reload this web page later.
 Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.
```

I have set the execution time and maxrequested length in web.config file.

```
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20480" executionTimeout="12000"/>
```

How can i solve this please help me..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" executionTimeout="0"/>
```

Here

```
executionTimeout="0" takes unlimited time
maxRequestLength="51200"    for 1mb=1024  so for 50mb=51200
```

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response,i have try without executiontime out in web.config it also showing error ....

Comment: executionTimeout has to be bigger than zero

Comment: That link now throws a malware warning on Google.

Comment: Thank you, this has worked for me, but what's the cause of this error? on my web site, i have nothing special, just a simple website. It start throwing this error when i replaced the css (css is 35kb)

Answer (score 2):

Just to make the answer more complete for the next guy:

httpRuntime goes in `<system.web>`

executionTimeout value of 0 only works for some versions of IIS